# Virtual machine/container that we can play flash clients after Jan 12 2021?

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-player-11

As it is announced years ago the Flash Player is going away.
https://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/end-of-life.html

However there are Flash apps that are not going away and even the end users don't use it, there is a value running them to see how the legacy systems worked.

So my question: is there a virtual machine image or container where we can still run flash players with the older versions of browsers and extensions? I see people are trying this approach but could not find a community effort.

Comment: As much as I love Flash and support its preservation, I don't think Stack Overflow is the right place to ask this.

Comment: This is probably on topic on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are virtual images that can do this.

Let me list all steps, total process takes around 15 mins (assuming you have a high speed connection)

I explained for virtual box but it is also doable for VMware.

1 - Go to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads and download and install Virtual Box

2 - Go to https://www.osboxes.org/linux-lite/#linux-lite-4-vbox and download and unzip Linux Lite 4.0   (Beware it is a 1.3GB download!!)

If you want VMware you can download VMware image too.

I tried with Linux Lite 4.6, it also works but don't use a higher version, they won't work.

3 - Create a new virtual machine (Linux, 64 bit) and select Linux Lite 4.0 (64bit).vdi as the "existing virtual harddisk file"

4 - Start the machine.

Username: osboxes
Password: osboxes.org

5 - Login, go to the Menu, hover over "Settings", and then open "Time and Date"

6 - "Unlock" and set the "Configuration" as "Manual". **Then select a date before Jan 12, 2021.** ( It may sync the time to normal again, if so unselect-select Manual again and now it will keep the time as what you set)

7 - Open Firefox, and go to your flash site such as : http://www.sfskids.org/play/

8 - Voilà! Music is there! and so your flash.

Comment: Thanks a ton - this helped a lot! The only caveat - the SSL certs and CAs are expiring and Firefox only allows to override/ignore a small subset of those :( Sometimes you can play a trickery of browser-caching under new date and then opening same site with past date, but a more-robust workarond (SSL proxy?) is needed. This topic needs to be moved to stackexchange (or whatever site it's "on topic" for)

Comment: To get around the caveat, I used https://thegeekpage.com/sec_error_ocsp_future_response/

Comment: Can I run web applications developed by Adobe Flex which uses Action Script 3 on those VM machines ?